# View over another view in percentage of screen width

Tags: react-native, percentage

I am new in react native and i want a view like attached image. I have no idea that how can achieved this..?

[image]

I have tried this:

**app.js**

```
            <View style={styles.navSectionStyle}>

              <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.SubmitButtonStyle}
                  activeOpacity = { .5 }
                  onPress={ this.ButtonClickCheckFunction }>

               <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> Page 1 </Text>

             </TouchableOpacity>

                <View style={styles.BackStyle}>

                <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> Test</Text>

                </View>

            </View>
```

**style.js**

```
    SubmitButtonStyle: {

        width:'70%', 
        height: 80 ,
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        alignItems: 'center',

        paddingTop:15,
        paddingBottom:15,

        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:10,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#fff'
      },

      BackStyle:{
      marginTop:10,
      marginLeft:15,
      position: 'absolute',
      width: 30,
      borderRadius:10,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#F53BBB',
      backgroundColor: '#F53BBB',
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      alignItems: 'center',
      shadowColor: '#000000',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 2,
          height: 3
        },
        shadowRadius: 4,
        shadowOpacity: 1.0
      },

      TextStyle:{
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      alignItems: 'center'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic template for the **View**

Get the Width of the screens using [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions) api.

Mark the views as `position: absolute` and get position them according to the *screen width*.

`15 %` from both sides, `10%` for overlapping view and `60%` for the main view

```
render() {
return (
 <View style={{flex: 1,
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
       backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
   <View style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6,
                 height: 100,
                 backgroundColor: 'blue'}}/>
   <View style={{position: 'absolute',
                 width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.1,
                 height: 80,
                 backgroundColor: 'black',
                 left: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.15,
                 zIndex: 1}} />
   <View style={{position: 'absolute',
                 width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.1,
                 height: 80,
                 backgroundColor: 'black', 
                 right:  Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.15,
                 zIndex: 1}} />
 </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: above view create in createStackNavigator drawer and using (Dimensions.get('window').width) i can get total screen width but how can i get or set  createStackNavigator drawer width custom..?

Comment: The default Drawer width is `screenWidth - headerWidth` equal to `Dimensions.get('window').width - (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 56 : 64)`, therefore you need to perform operations on this width for a Drawer. If you have provided a custom `drawerWidth` then you need to perform operations on that width.